# How can I get the "outline" of a Path stroke, and get the points to create a filled Path shape?

Tags: javascript, canvas, path, html5-canvas, shapes

I want to retrieve the corresponding points to a 'outlinestroke' and save it as a Shape, instead of a "path with a stroke"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineWidth = 12;
ctx.lineCap = 'round'
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(20, 100, 200, 20);
ctx.stroke();
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

This is the result of the code:

[image: Curve on canvas]

But I want to have the Outline of this stroke, and turn it into a Path and give it a stroke.
The fill should be transparent.
And only have a small outline.

Is there a way to "trace or convert" the stroke to a outline path to get the following result:

[image]

And if this is not possible:
Before drawing, to use the given points to define the shape of a path.

Here is what I tried:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var width = 12;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineWidth = width;
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(20, 100, 200, 20);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.fillStyle = "#ccc";

ctx.moveTo(20-width/2, 270);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(20-width/2, 350+width/2, 200-width/2, 270+width/2);
ctx.lineTo(200-width/2, 270-width/2);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(20+width/2, 350-width/2, 20+width/2, 270-width/2);
ctx.lineTo(20-width/2, 270);
ctx.fillStyle = "#999";

ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are no API features to turn a strokes outline into a path.

You can however use a [composite operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) to create the inner transparency.

### Example

Creating outline using [`globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation)

The gradient is just to show it is transparent.

```js
const OUTLINE_WIDTH = 1; // in pixels

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 22;
ctx.lineCap = 'round'
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(20, 100, 200, 20);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
ctx.lineWidth = 22 - OUTLINE_WIDTH * 2;
ctx.stroke();

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // restore default
```

```css
canvas {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(180,255,224,1) 0%, rgba(169,169,255,1) 100%);
    
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```