# HTML5 Canvas - How to render a transparent line with colored border

Tags: colors, html5-canvas, border

I'm currently using Canvas to draw some curved lines

I know how to draw colored lines, but I don't find a way to render them with **only** a colored border..

For example :

```js
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(100, 10, 150, 75);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(200, 140, 300, 100);

// this draws a 20px thick red line
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas width="350" height="150" style="border: 1px #303030 solid"></canvas>
```

I tried with `clip()`, but it's not built to cut a line...

Is there a way to draw a real border around a thick line, to avoid filling it ?

**I don't want to re-draw a thinner colored line over it**, because I'm using a transparent canvas within a parent DOM element filled with an image (and don't want to move this background into the canvas)

Answer (score 1):

I found a **not perfect** solution in a [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64339925/how-can-i-get-the-outline-of-a-path-stroke-and-get-the-points-to-create-a-fil), using [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation)

```js
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  borderWidth = 1;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(100, 10, 150, 75);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(200, 140, 300, 100);

// this draws a 20px thick red line
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
ctx.stroke();

// just add this
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
ctx.lineWidth = 20 - borderWidth * 2;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

```html
<canvas width="350" height="150" style="border: 1px #303030 solid"></canvas>
```

In my case, it cut a double-hole into the canvas ; and it doesn't work if you have another background *into* the canvas...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(100, 10, 150, 75);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(200, 140, 275, 100);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(285, 110,275, 120);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(200, 160, 150, 95);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(100, 30, 20, 40);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(10, 30, 20, 20);

ctx.lineWidth = 2;
//ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';
ctx.stroke();
//ctx.fill();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're an artist xD I'm not a big fan of this solution, the result isn't perfect, and my example was a simplified version of huge calculations I have in a real project...

Comment: Yeah, you right! ;)